# rrule in future but relative to this morning

Tags: python, rrule, python-dateutil

I'm trying to calculate the next point in time which complies with some simple rules.

Only include Weekdays mentioned in a list (in the example below, Mon-Fri). Return only hours which are listed (12:00, 18:00).

I'd like to get the first such point, starting from the `After` date provided.

I've got as far as this but it's returning an 'unrounded' time which just seems to be a constant offset from the current time

```
def NextRunTime(After=django.utils.timezone.now()):
    Sched = {'Hours': [12,18], 'Days': [0,1,2,3,4]}
    rule = DateRule.rrule(DateRule.HOURLY,
                byweekday=Sched['Days'],
                byhour=Sched['Hours'],
                dtstart=After,
                count=1)
    return rule[0]
```

This is currently returning `2013-05-01 18:53:39+01` which seems to be relative to the current time of day.

Can someone tell me how I can get rrule to use times relative to midnight but return dates after `After`?

Explicit examples of desired output

```
After           Output
Mon 10:11:12    Mon 12:00:00
Mon 11:22:33    Mon 12:00:00
Mon 12:00:01    Mon 18:00:00
Fri 12:00:01    Fri 18:00:00
Fri 18:00:01    Mon 12:00:00 (Following Monday)
```

Comment: Can you give some examples of the desired output (given explicit values for `After`)?

Comment: @unutbu Done - hope that's clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [bysetpos = 1](http://labix.org/python-dateutil). This parameter causes `rrule` to return datetimes which are at "position 1" in a set of matches. "position 1" is relative to the `byweekday`, `byhour`, `byminute`, `bysecond`, etc. So by setting `byminute=0` and `bysecond=0`, and `bysetpos=1`, `rrule` always returns hour 12 or hour 18:

```
import dateutil.rrule as DateRule
import datetime as DT

def NextRunTime(After):
    Sched = {'Hours': [12,18], 'Days': [0,1,2,3,4]}
    rule = DateRule.rrule(DateRule.HOURLY,
                          byweekday=Sched['Days'],
                          byhour=Sched['Hours'],
                          byminute=0,
                          bysecond=0,
                          bysetpos=1,
                          # dtstart=After means rule might return After
                          dtstart=After,
                          # To ensure NextRunTime returns something after After, use
                          # dtstart=After+DT.timedelta(seconds=1), 
                          count=1)
    return rule[0]

tests = [
    (DT.datetime(2013,4,29,10,11,12),
     DT.datetime(2013,4,29,12,0,0)),
    (DT.datetime(2013,4,29,11,22,33),
     DT.datetime(2013,4,29,12,0,0)),
    (DT.datetime(2013,4,29,12,0,1),
     DT.datetime(2013,4,29,18,0,0)),
    (DT.datetime(2013,5,3,12,0,1),
     DT.datetime(2013,5,3,18,0,0)),
    (DT.datetime(2013,5,3,18,0,1),
     DT.datetime(2013,5,6,12,0,0)),
    (DT.datetime(2013,4,29,12,0,0),  # Note that NextRunTime(After) returns After
     DT.datetime(2013,4,29,12,0,0)),
    ]

for After, answer in tests:
    result = NextRunTime(After)
    try:
        assert result == answer
    except AssertionError:
        print('''\
result:
{result}
answer:
{answer}
'''.format(**locals()))
        raise
```

Answer (score 1):

You should either use `dtstart` with minutes=0 and seconds=0 or chop the time from the returned value yourself.

Because this is how `rrule` is expected to work - it adds some intervals to the passed `dtstart`, which in your case includes minutes and seconds.

Comment: I can't chop the minutes/seconds from `dtstart` as that might result in a "hit" in the past. Stripping them from the output is an option though

Comment: You could pass the nearest hour in the future as `dtstart`